# Jersey @Ref (Declarative Hyperlinking) in Arbitrarily Nested Sub Resources

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I've googled around a good bit and tried to dig into [Jersey source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server-linking/1.17/com/sun/jersey/server/linking/impl/RefProcessor.java?av=f), but as far as I can tell, Jersey does not support arbitrarily deep nesting of sub resources in conjunction with `@Ref` annotations.

Here's my set up:

**MemberResource.java**

```java
@Component // Spring managed
@Scope("prototype")
@Validated
@Path("/member")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MemberResource extends BaseResource {

    @Autowired // Spring is injecting this sub resource
    private MemberFriendResource memberFriendResource;

    @Path("/{memberId}/friend/")
    public MemberFriendResource getMemberFriendResource() {
        return memberFriendResource;
    }

}
```

**MemberFriendResource.java**

```java
@Component // Spring managed
@Scope("prototype")
@Validated
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MemberFriendResource extends BaseResource {

    @GET
    public JResponse<FriendListRepresentation> getAllFriends() {
        // Code
    }


    @GET
    @Path("/recent")
    public JResponse<FriendListRepresentation> getRecentFriends() {
        // Code
    }
}
```

**MemberRepresentation.java**

```java
public class MemberRepresentation {
    @Ref(resource=MemberResource.class, method="getMemberFriendResource", bindings = {
    @Binding(name="memberId", value="${instance.id}")
    })
    public URI allFriendsURI;

    @Ref(resource=MemberResource.class, method="??????????", bindings = {
    @Binding(name="memberId", value="${instance.id}")
    })
    public URI recentFriendsURI;
}
```

I want to have the `recentFriendsURI` dynamically generated just like the `allFriendsURI` (which itself does work, just to be clear). I realize that I can manually type out the path, along the lines of `@Ref(value="/member/{memberId}/friend/recent", etc)`, but I would strongly, *strongly* prefer not to hard code my path strings in every random representation that needs the link.

**Is it possible with Jersey to have a URI to a sub resource method injected with variables properly bound using the resource/method paradigm rather than typing out the String path?**

I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885383/is-it-correct-that-jersey-does-not-support-declarative-hyperlinking-in-nested-re) is trying to achieve a similar, but slightly different result.
[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9617107/1449525) is, I think, a more specific form of my question. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't hard code the path and can be arbitrarily deep.